# How to easily crop the same image multiple times

Tags: image, image-processing, photoshop

I have a set of really *big* images out of which I need to crop little snippets. These snippets are all exactly the same size but don't follow a strict pattern so I can't do this programatically.

Ideally I would like to open up one of the big files and be able to point and click on say, the top left corner of a snippet and have that automatically be saved to disk without even having to enter a file name, and then continue on with the rest. (Of course this would be the ideal way which I know is probably way off the real possible way!).

I started doing this in Photoshop CS4 but cropping a snippet, saving, undoing (to get to the full image), and starting over again takes way too long.

Maybe someone has a better way to do this in photoshop or in some other software.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: This is a better question for SuperUser or one of the StackExchange sites such as photography.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of such sites! I'll look them up and try over there. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your input.

I ended up doing this with a suggestion a colleague of mine came up with. It consisted of creating a Photoshop "slice" over the first region I wanted to crop and then cloning that region over the rest of the other sections. After that, using Save For Web (and ofter hitting Continue when PS complained about how that image was way beyond Save For Web's capabilities) I could save all images at once. 
This was the fastest and easiest method I could find. Until then I was going with Mark Ransom's method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of cropping and undoing, you could:

- make (or resize) a selection
- copy the selection to a new image
- save the image
- close the image

You might need to split it into two actions, I don't know enough about programming Photoshop.

Comment: Mark, I'll give this a shot and will post back the results.